# Changes made while iterating over dataframe dont save

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe which has "duplicate" rows in a way. Let's say i have a row `A = ['name' : john, 'age' : 15, 'email' : NaN, 'school' : middle]` and a row `B = ['name' : john, 'age' : 15, 'email' : john@gmail.com, 'school' : NaN]`. The resulting rows for both A and B should be `['name' : john, 'age' : 15, 'email' : john@gmail.com, 'school' : middle]`.

So far i have tried using iterrows() over a dataframe and changing the values but the changes don't save.
My code:

```
duplicated = df[df.duplicated(['name', 'age'], keep = False)].sort_values('name')
row_iterator = duplicated.iterrows()

_, last = row_iterator.__next__()
for k, row in row_iterator:
    if row['name'] == last['name']:
        for i in duplicated.columns:
            if row[i] == last[i]:
                continue
            if pd.isna(row[i]):
                row[i] = last[i]
            if pd.isna(last[i]):
                last[i] = row[i]
    last = row
```

df is the name of the dataframe where I have all the data. Then i cut only the duplicate rows into `duplicated`. After that I iterate through the dataframe and try to make changes as I go. But the changes I make get lost or something in the end. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways we can solve your problem:

**Method 1**: using `bfill`, `ffill` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df = df.bfill().ffill().drop_duplicates()

   name  age           email  school
0  john   15  john@gmail.com  middle
```

**Method 2**: `GroupBy.first`:

```
df = df.groupby(['name', 'age']).first().reset_index()

   name  age           email  school
0  john   15  john@gmail.com  middle
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the quick reply. I tried the second method and it's working very nicely. The only problem is it changes the order of the rows, is there any way I can avoid that? I also tried the first method but it was giving me weird numbers, like halving the non-NaN value.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. Best way is to provide an example dataframe, where I can see what happens by applying my method. This way I can adjust my method accordingly.

Comment: @Erfan `groupby` with `sort=False`?

Comment: Very nice. Groupby with sort=False works. Thank you!